# Easiest way to mark differences between two observables of arrays

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am pretty new to angular and rxjs.

What is the easiest way of finding a difference between two arrays which are being emitted by observables?

In the example below I am trying to get the array of available Roles, get the array of assigned Roles.

My goal is to mark those roles which are in both the `allRoles$` array and the `assignedRoles$` array:

```js
getAvailableUserRoles(userId: string): Observable < Role[] > {
    const allRoles$: Observable<Role[]> = this.getRoles();
    const assignedRoles$: Observable<Role[]> = this.getUserRoles(userId);

    forkJoin([allRoles$, assignedRoles$])
    .pipe(
        map(([allRoles, assignedRoles]) => {
            for (const allRole of allRoles) {
                for (const assignedRole of assignedRoles) {
                    if (assignedRole.id === allRole.id) {
                        allRole.assigned = true;
                    } else
                        allRole.assigned = false;
                }
            }
        }));
    return allRoles$;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right basically:

```js
getAvailableUserRoles(userId: string): Observable < Role[] > {
    const allRoles$: Observable<Role[]> = this.getRoles();
    const assignedRoles$: Observable<Role[]> = this.getUserRoles(userId);

    return forkJoin([allRoles$, assignedRoles$])
        .pipe(
            map(([allRoles, assignedRoles]) => {
                allRoles.forEach(role => {
                    role.assigned = !!assignedRoles.find(assignedRole => role.id === assignedRole.id));
                });
                return allRoles;
            }));
}
```